# MAGENTO 2.3.3 ups carrier model plugin getting error

Tags: magento2.3.3

Magento 2.3.3 Getting below error when creating **plugin** for **`Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier`** class

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing
>   required argument $data of Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier.
>
> Exception #0 (BadMethodCallException): Missing required argument $data
>   of Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier.

As my understand issue is because of class::__construct last param (newly added in to 2.3.3) `$proxyDeferredFactory` is not follow compatibility

> Magento\Ups\Model\Carrier::__construct (last parameter should be null)

It should be `null` require

Consider basic knowledge of Plugin!

Welcome suggestion to work with lower MAGENTO version also.

Comment: did you get any solution for that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Will be fixed in Magento 2.4. See https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/cfd5c22848f82f29f69cd42ffbcc8e09fa848568.
Workaround: Replace the following line:

```
?ProxyDeferredFactory $proxyDeferredFactory
```

with

```
?ProxyDeferredFactory $proxyDeferredFactory = null
```

in the constructor arguments

Comment: This answer saves my weekends.

Comment: Just adding on that you may also need to run setup:di:compile as well

Comment: @Keith Yes, but only if you are running on production mode. On developer mode that command is not needed.